# Creating php file

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem where I can not retrieve the result from my MySQL database (via PHP). I use the same function in other places and it works flawlessly. However at this point i keep getting the "Warning: mysqli_query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli" error.
heres my php code:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "123456";
$dbName = "cool_yt_rpg";

//Make Connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbName);
//Check Connection
if(!$conn){
   die("Connection Failed."  . mysqli_connect_error());
 }

$sql = "SELECT ID, Name, Type, Cost FROM items";
$result = mysqli_query($conn ,$sql);
   
if(mysqli_num_rows ($result)){ 
   //show data for each row
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
         echo "ID:" .$row['ID'] . "Name:" .$row['Name'] . "Type:".$row['Type'] . "Cost:" .$row['Cost'] . "<br>";
      }
}
?>
```

and i got this error:

> Warning: mysqli::mysqli() [mysqli.mysqli]: (28000/1045): Access denied for     user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in   C:\xampp\htdocs\Cool_YT_RPG\ItemsData.php on line 8
>
> Warning: mysqli_query() [function.mysqli-query]: Couldn't fetch mysqli in   C:\xampp\htdocs\Cool_YT_RPG\ItemsData.php on line 15
>
> Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Cool_YT_RPG\ItemsData.php on line 17

Comment: on the first line, it said that it was unable to connect your database.Are you sure you provide the right identifier?

Comment: wrong credentials. Fix that and the rest will follow. If you didn't originally assign a password to your install, remove it. `$password = "";` and/or make sure you have granted permissions.

Comment: Can you login with these credentials on the command line?

Answer (score -1):

Looks like `$result` is coming back null for some reason.  You'll want to investigate why.

That said, you could do this so it doesn't crash when that happens:

```
if(isset($result) && mysqli_num_rows ($result))
```

And then print some kind of error message in an else block.

Comment: Well i think the error is in his connection. As you can see the first error is `Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'`

Comment: As true as that is, I have provided a way to prevent total program failure when that occurs (that info was also not in the question when I posted).  Null-checks are generally a good idea, even when you don't expect them to happen (the number of times I've said to myself, "this will never be null" only to find out weeks or months later that *yes, actually it can be* is more than I can count).